# Finding similar/related texts algorithms

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, similarity

I searched a lot in stackoverflow and Google but I didn't find the best answer for this.
Actually, I'm going to develop a news reader system that crawl and collect news from web (with a crawler) and then, I want to find similar or related news in websites (In order to prevent showing duplicated news in website)

I think the best live example for that is Google News, it collect news from web and then categorize and find related news and articles. This is what I want to do.

What's the best algorithm for doing this?

Comment: In my opinion you may use a Bayesian network but a good one isn't so trivial to implement.

Comment: can we have a chat : http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21749/nlp-for-news

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A relatively simple solution is to compute a tf-idf vector (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf*idf) for each document, then use the cosine distance (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) between these vectors as an estimate for semantic distance between articles.

This will probably capture semantic relationships better than Levenstein distance and is much faster to compute.

Answer (score 1):

This is one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

```
public static SqlInt32 ComputeLevenstheinDistance(SqlString firstString, SqlString secondString)
{
    int n = firstString.Value.Length;
    int m = secondString.Value.Length;
    int[,] d = new int[n + 1,m + 1];

    // Step 1
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return m;
    }

    if (m == 0)
    {
        return n;
    }

    // Step 2
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++)
    {
    }

    for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++)
    {
    }

    // Step 3
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        //Step 4
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
        {
            // Step 5
            int cost = (secondString.Value[j - 1] == firstString.Value[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

            // Step 6
            d[i, j] = Math.Min(Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1), d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
        }
    }
    // Step 7
    return d[n, m];
}
```

This is handy for the task at hand: http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/

Also, if you need to reduce the number of words to analyze, try this: http://ots.codeplex.com/

I have found the OTS VERY useful in sentiment analysis, whereby I can reduce the number of sentences into a small list of common phrases and/or words and calculate the overall sentiment based on this.  The same should work for similarity.

Comment: Well Levensthein distance is good if it's OK to collect news abound "sand", about "sad" people and "mad" cows. It could be good for "autocomplete" or spell checker suggestions but not to extract the meaning of words!